# How to make ng build watching multiple apps?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I need to build 2 applications (New1 and New2) with watch option, so any files changes in any of those 2 apps lead to re-build.

`ng build New1 && ng build New2` works fine, I can see both apps built under /dist directory,
but I cannot get `ng build --watch` to work the same way. So far I tried:

1) `ng build New1 && ng build New2 --watch`
Builds both apps, but then only watches New2.
If I make changes to New1, the build doesn't happen again.

2) `ng build New1 --watch && ng build New2 --watch`
Only builds New1 app and watches it.

3) `ng build New1 --output-path dist/New1 && ng build New2 --output-path dist/New2 --watch`
Builds both apps, but then only watches New2.

4) `ng build New1 --output-path dist/New1 --watch && ng build New2 --output-path dist/New2 --watch`
Only builds New1 app and watches it.

Is there a way to use build --watch for 2 apps in one line at all?

Appreciate the suggestions.

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.4
Node: 10.11.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.8.4
@angular-devkit/core         0.8.4
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.8.4
@schematics/angular          0.8.4
@schematics/update           0.8.4
rxjs                         6.2.2
typescript                   2.9.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to run 2 calls at the same time, I'd suggest the `concurrently` package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

It's pretty easy to combine calls. You would add a new script to package.json and combine 2 commands. Below has not been tested with your code so please read the docs:

`"build:concurrent": "concurrently \"ng build New1 --watch\" \"ng build New2 --watch\"",`

You would then run it in the terminal using `npm run build:concurrent`

Comment: first check showed it logs the changes but the files in /dist weren't updated. Will dig into this further, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

The reason `ng build New1 --watch && ng build New2 --watch` doesn't work, is because the first build needs to finish before the second starts.

My solution? Just open two terminals and run one `build --watch` in each. If you're using VS Code's built-in terminal, they will be in two different tabs, but will work together.

**Edit: Plan B**

Assuming you're on Windows, the `start` command opens a new terminal and returns.

So you could use this, and it should work just fine:

```
start ng build New1 --watch && start ng build New2 --watch
```

Comment: two terminals is the option, but what I really need is to add a single-lined script to package.json file

Comment: @Sveta I updated the answer with a way to automate it.